# Error when using firebase authentication Angular: "TypeError: app.messaging is not a function"

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpe8F.png)          I'm working on an Angular project and I'm trying to implement AngularFireMessaging for push      notifications. However, I'm encountering the following error:

````
ERROR TypeError: app.messaging is not a function
   at AngularFireMessaging.<anonymous> (angular-fire-compat-messaging.js:29:24)
    // ... rest of the error stack

      I'm using AngularFire and AngularFireCompat in my project. I've followed the              documentation, but I'm still stuck with this error.




 i am using firebase authentication for my project but stuck by this error ,

my angular version is 

  ```
"@angular/core": "~16.2.4",
 ```

and firebase version is
````

```
 "firebase": "^10.3.1",
```

"@angular/fire": "^7.6.1",

how can i resolve  this